# How to set Series Opacity in Google Sheets Embedded (Scatter) Chart with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I set this value using Google App Script?

I have followed the guidance in [this reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#scatter-chart-configuration-options), but there isn't an option listed to control the opacity of the series. Other chart types (such as Combo Chart) support this option, but Scatter Chart does not.

However, as you can see in the image, there is an option available through the user interface that allows the opacity of a series point in a Scatter Chart to be changed...so we know that it must be possible. How?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve opacity by modifying the color since the color attribute accepts rgba input next to hex. Instead of #000000 you add rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5).

```
function opacity() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SHEETNAME");

var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('colors', ['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'])
    .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

I have tested the code and it works:
[image]